# Finding position of element within scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these "pages" aka `div`'s inside a scrollable container. On command, I am trying to find out what part of the div in question, is touching the top of `.pageContent`.

So for example, right when the page loads, no part of `#page_1` is touching the top of `pageContent`, but as I scroll down. `#page_1` hits the top of `.pageContent` and I now want to figure out where that is.

I know I can get the position of `.pageContent` using `$("#pageContent").scrollTop()` but these page's could be different sizes and I am not sure how to go about figuring it out.

Could anyone put me in the right direction?

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5aaLo9L/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="pageContent">
    <div id="page_1" class="content"></div>
    <div id="page_2" class="content"></div>
    <div id="page_3" class="content"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#pageContent {
    overflow: auto;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:grey;
}
.content {
    height:400px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:red;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery .position() function to compute where each page is in relation to the top of the container. See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/yh4nxt18/).

For example, for #page_1,

```
var page1 = $('#page_1');
$('#pageContent').scroll(function() {
    // page1.position().top gives the position of page_1 relative to the
    // top of #pageContent
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollTop` can be used, be I wouldn't recommend it.

Attach a scroll event to your main div and listener for all the objects inside:

```
$('#pageContent').scroll(function(){

    var pages = $("#pageContent > .content");
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++)
    {
        if ($(pages[i]).position().top < 0 && ( $(pages[i]).position().top + $(pages[i]).outerHeight() ) > 0) 
        {
            var outerHeight = $(pages[i]).outerHeight();
            var pixels = (outerHeight - (outerHeight + $(pages[i]).position().top));

            console.log("These pixels are in view between: " + pixels + " and " + outerHeight );
        }
    }

})
```

Every time the div scroll a loop is performed checking the position of all elements. If the elements scroll out of view a the top the if is triggered, calculating the remaining visible pixels of the page currently visible.

This uses jQuery's: `position()` and `outerHeight()` and JavaScript's native `offsetTop`.

http://jsfiddle.net/q5aaLo9L/4/

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $('.content').map(function (i, el) {
        return $(el).offset().top - $(el).parent().offset().top;
    });
    $('#pageContent').scroll(function () {
        var index = findIndex($(this).scrollTop(), divs) - 1;
        if (index > -1) {
            console.log($(this).children().eq(index).attr('id'));
        } else {
            console.log('outside');
        }

    });
});

function findIndex(pos, divs) {
    return (divs.filter(function (el, et) {
        return et <= pos
    }).length);
}
```

It's not super clean code because I had to do it quickly. 
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/q5aaLo9L/5/)
I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I mocked this up, it uses JQuery's each() function to iterate through the pages and return the information of the page that has breached the top of the box.

I wasn't sure from your question exactly what you wanted returned, so I got it to return either the percentage of the page that has cleared the top border, the position (as negative value of pixels) of the top of the "page " in relation to the content container, and also just the ID of that div.

```
var getCurrentPage = function(){

    var page;
    var position; 
    var percentageRead; 

    $('.content').each(function(){ 

        if($(this).position().top <= 0){ 
           page = $(this);
           position = $(this).position().top;
        } 

    });


    percentageRead = ((position *-1)/ $(page).height()* 100); 


    console.log(page.attr('id'));
    console.log(position);
    console.log(percentageRead + '%');

}

$('#pageContent').on('scroll', getCurrentPage);
```

You could fire this on any event but I used scroll to build it.